# Unable to dismissViewControllerAnimated iOS 9.3

Tags: swift2, uialertcontroller, ios9.3

I am showing an `UIAlertController` and in `UIAlertAction` I am dismissing view controller. It was working fine prior to iOS 9.3. But in iOS 9.3 it is not working. Following is the code.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Logged In Successfully", message: "asda", preferredStyle: .Alert)

 // Create the actions
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { UIAlertAction in
                            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                        }

                        // Add the actions
                        alertController.addAction(okAction)

                        // Present the controller
                        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put breakpoint in the dismissViewControllerAnimated line, and check if it's getting there when you press OK.

If it's not - try to replace

```
UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { UIAlertAction in
                            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                        }
```

with this:

```
UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { _ in
                            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                        }
```

Comment: I have added break points. Alertcontroller is working but dismissViewController is not executing.

Comment: Did you tried to replace the UIAlertAction param to _  ?